# Spark Job failing with error - saying class is not found

Tags: apache-spark

While trying to run a streaming job, joining two kafka topics, I am getting this issue.

```
 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 2bef1ea4-4493-4e20-afe9- 
 9ce2d86ccd50, runId = fe233b26-37f0-49b2-9c0b-dd7d91146dc3] terminated with error
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
 org/apache/spark/sql/internal/connector/SupportsStreamingUpdate
```

Verified both the versions of `Kafka` and `Spark` and they are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The error generally means the jar file of the class is not in the runtime classpath, although it is available during compilation. Do the following:

1. Find the jar file
2. Check for version compatibility
3. Add it to your runtime classpath